# Multitasking in Python, Reformat and Move

Tags: python-3.x, multitasking

I have a many folders. I want to make .zip format of files and move them to another directory:

```
    for (dir, dirs, files) in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
             # make zip files
             if filename.endswith(".zip"):
                # move created zip files
                os.rename(dir + '/' + filename, new + '/' + directory + '/' + filename)
```

The problem is that, after make the zip file, program couldn't find the created file with zip extension. I want to create a zip format and move it to another folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shutil lib:

```
import shutil
shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

> shutil.move(src, dst)
>
> Recursively move a file or directory (src) to another location (dst).
>
> If the destination is an existing directory, then src is moved inside
> that directory. If the destination already exists but is not a
> directory, it may be overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics.
>
> If the destination is on the current filesystem, then os.rename() is
> used. Otherwise, src is copied (using shutil.copy2()) to dst and then
> removed.

---

Also you can use shutil for archive file:

> shutil.make_archive(base_name, format[, root_dir[, base_dir[,
> verbose[, dry_run[, owner[, group[, logger]]]]]]])
>
> Create an archive
> file (such as zip or tar) and return its name.

For more info read [shutil documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

Comment: I have edited my question. My problem is that when I have so many files, os.walk(directory) reads old files, not newly created files.

Comment: @TheNone , Once you've changed the file name, You won't see the change untill you will run again the os.walk.  Once the line of code of the os.walk is passed, You have the result. In order to see changes you need to call again to os.walk that way you will get new result. It's not possible to see the change while the iteration of the loop.

Comment: @TheNone , Even if does, it's not a good practice to loop over an iterable and update the irerable inside the loop.

Comment: But what do you suggest? Bulk update and then bulk move? (this was what I did before)

Comment: @TheNone , If you have many files, bulk is a good option. If there are only few, you could do all in one.